# 2 SQL Queries from same table

Tags: php, sql, mysql, union

I am looking to grab the first row (ordered by `date` descending) from a table, and then grab the rest of the rows (ordered by `last_name` ascending). I'm assuming I need to use a UNION statement for this, but I'm having trouble getting it to work.

Thanks in advance

Comment: is `date` in and of itself guaranteed to be unique?

Comment: What is your table structure? Do you have a PK?

Comment: The date is not unique because it is a timestamp imported from a date format. And yes I have a PK called `id`.

Comment: There's an ANSI standard for limiting rows, but no two databases currently use it.  So what database is this for?

Comment: As it is tagged PHP, its 95% or more likely that it's MySQL... it would be nice to have that confirmed though.

Comment: It is in fact a MySQL database. Sorry for not clarifying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM yourtable
ORDER BY
    id = (SELECT id FROM yourtable ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 1) DESC,
    last_name
```

Answer (score 2):

Why not run two queries?  That seems like one obvious answer.

Not every task needs to be done in a single query.  Do you write all your PHP code in one statement as well?  ;-)

Comment: I know it would make more sense to do it separately (and I normally would), but without getting too much into the details, it would be much easier if there were a way to do it in 1 query.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming using MySQL, you could use:

```
 (SELECT t.*
    FROM TABLE t
ORDER BY t.date DESC
   LIMIT 1)
UNION 
 (SELECT t.*
    FROM TABLE t
ORDER BY t.last_name)
```

You need to encapsulate the statements in brackets to apply the ORDER BY - otherwise, ORDER BY is applied to the resultset after the UNION.

Comment: This will include that first row twice, once at the top and again lower, which the poster probably doesn't want.

Comment: @Scott Stafford: No, it won't because UNION removes duplicates.  You'd be correct if it were `UNION ALL`